# jQuery attribute selector: anything but not ending with specified string?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

I need to select elements in jquery, attibute values of which **do not end with a specified substring**.

It must be an equivalent to "*match all elements but those that end with a given substring in that attribute*".

So that `e[a!@#=finstr]` matches e, e `a="finstring"` etc, and does NOT match e `a="somethingfinstr"`, e `a="finstr"`.

Help, thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
$(':not([name$="finstr"])')
```

Should do the trick!

Edit: alternatively

```
$(selector).not('[name$="value"]');
```

Comment: I guess you have you wrap `name$="finstr"` in `[` `]`

Comment: But if I have a class '.editable:not([name$=".notthis"]) - I wonder what change is needed to get it to work

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work, using links as an example -

```
$("a:not([id$='hello'])"
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/CJH2M/

Answer (score 1):

Try inverting the: Attribute Ends With Selector [name$="value"].
with jQuery(':not(selector)').

Something like this: **:not([name$="value"])**

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('*').not('[attribute$="finishstring"]')
```