# Using multiple jquery selectors for href contains

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to prevent a specific div from displaying when any given url opens a new window/tab (which works), or when the url ends with .csv or .xlsx. When I add the .csv/.xlsx part to my selectors, the loading function is never reached. Any help is appreciated!

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', "a[target!='_blank'], a[href$!='.csv'], a[href$!='.xlsx']", loading);
});
```

Comment: `$!=` is not a valid attribute selector. Check your Javascript console, you're probably getting an error from this.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307493/jquery-attribute-selector-anything-but-not-ending-with-specified-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use `:not` for the negation of the selector.

```
$(document).on('click', "a[target!='_blank'], a:not([href$='.csv']),a:not([href$='.xlsx'])", loading)
```

Comment: +1, as I didn't notice the anchor problem in my answer

Comment: For whatever reason mixing the a[...] and a:not([...]) didn't work for me. I converted my code to `$(document).on('click', "a:not([target='_blank'],[href$='.csv'],[href$='.xlsx'])", loading)` which resolved my problem. Thanks for getting me on the right track!!